# How to Find the assembly where an object had been created?

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to find the first place where an object has been created:(When it's constructor has been called).
ex: Let's say I have `A objA= new A();` in a DLL "DLL_A". The objA obejct has been passed via many calls until we arrived to a DLL_B where we handle this object "objA".

Is there any reflection method/way to know in DLL_B that the Object Obj_A is created in DLL_A ?

Comment: Try `objA.GetType().Assembly.Location` or if you just want to know which assembly then `objA.GetType().Assembly`.

Comment: So, to be clear - you're not looking for the assembly where the `A` class is *defined*, you want to find, essentially, what the call stack looked like at the point at which the object was constructed? If so, no. There's no such feature built in. If `A`s constructor can be changed, it could capture this information, but this smells like the wrong solution to a problem you've not defined.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes that's my point. the Assembly,Class and the method where this object was crerated

Comment: Like I say, the only way to do that is to muck about with `A`s constructor, but it smells really bad. Could you, instead, tell us what *problem* you're trying to solve where this is part of your attempted solution?

Comment: Well it's not a real problem but it comes to my mind this Idea. I m creating a Model in my Controller or my ViewModel then processing it until I reach the Repository layer. And I said :Can I know Which ViewModel has created this Model ?

Comment: Why does it matter which viewmodel that created the model? And is the model actually created by the viewmodel, or injected through the container?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen For the first question to know from which screen the object was created? And for the second question The object is created by the viewModel

Comment: But why do you want / need to know which screen created the object? What kind of logic do you want to base off of that knowledge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want a property in `A`, which returns the name / method of the class which called the constructor of `A`. Correct?

Then you could use the [Caller Information in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx): the `CallerFilePathAttribute`, `CallerLineNumberAttribute`, `CallerMemberNameAttribute` could be used as optional parameters in the constructor of `A`.

These information can then be saved while still in the constructor in a field / property and later be retreived.

Comment: @Micky the idea would be storing the caller inside the object (inside `A`) so it can be checked later